# Error : subclasses of BaseDatabaseOperations may require a datetime_extract_sql() method... in Django date filtering

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, django-views, filtering

I'm using Django 2.2.12.

In models.py, I have a model of name `Webregister` having field

`created_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)` that returns data in the format `2020-09-04 22:17:00+00:00`

Inorder to filter the date, I wrote this query

`Webregister.objects.filter(created_on__date=date.today())`

and it returns the following error,

`NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseOperations may require a datetime_extract_sql() method`

However, it's working fine If I use `__year` and hit the following query,

`Webregister.objects.filter(created_on__year="2020")`

PLease let me know what's the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

you can just use normal filter with datetime or date objects as long as they are comparable :

```
class Model(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)


data = Model.objects.filter(created_on__exact=datetime.now())
```

Your error is probably the comparaison between your `DateTimeField()` (which is a `datetime` object) and `date.now()` (which is a `date` object)

You can also use `lt`, `gt` but the two data need to be comparable